# Complexity of the following algorithm to generate TaxiCab numbers?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, time-complexity

Following is an algorithm for generating Taxicab numbers using a priority queue(`pq`). `Vector` is an arbitrary data type that allows for storage of two number and their cubed sum. For those unaware(although you really don't need to know), a taxicab number is an integer that can be expressed as the sum of two cubes of integers in two different ways: `a^3+b^3 = c^3+d^3`. An example would be `1729 = 12^3 + 1^3 = 10^3 + 9^3`

```
for i = 1..n
 pq.insert( Vector(i^3+i^3,i,i) )

prev = Vector(0, 0, 0)

while not pq.empty()
 curr = pq.deleteMin()
 if prev[0] == curr[0]
      print curr[0] is a Taxicab number that can be expressed as
      prev[1]^3 + prev[2]^3 and curr[1]^3 + curr[2]^3
 prev = curr
 if curr[2] < N
     j = curr[2] + 1
     pq.insert( Vector(curr[1]^3 + j^3, curr[1], j) )
```

I know inserting an item into the priority queue is `O(log n)` but I am not sure how this relate to space and time complexity. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely no worst than `O(N^2 log N)`, though it might be possible to give tighter bounds for it.

This block of code:

```
if curr[2] < N
    j = curr[2] + 1
    pq.insert( Vector(curr[1]^3 + j^3, curr[1], j) )
```

Makes the code roughly equivalent, but somewhat more efficient than:

```
possibles = empty list
for i = 1..n
   for j in i+1..n
       possibles.append( Vector(i^3 + j^3, i, j) )
sort(possible_numbers)

for i = 1..n
    prev = possibles[i]
    curr = possibles[i + 1]
    if prev[0] == curr[0]
        print curr[0] is a Taxicab number that can be expressed as
        prev[1]^3 + prev[2]^3 and curr[1]^3 + curr[2]^3
```

The size of the possibles list `O(N^2)`, making sorting it `O(N^2 log(N))`. The second loop is `O(N)` which makes the code `O(N^2 log N)`.